# Column rows to column headers in Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I have a data set where I would like to have a table with Unique IDs in one Column A and from Column B the rows from a "Input" table above with a different rows as a column headers. In Column A are IDs (unique) and Column B has different rows that have to be in columns but matching values on the rest of the columns.. see on screenshot.

Third Column C is a just observational column that gives info what kind of data type should be there (it can be avoided in this case).

I though I was going to solve it "easily" with Pivot/Unpivot+Transponse method in Power Query but no way....I can get it in one row like in "Output" table..

The dummy data is in link below.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qKeVj9nJF1usBk-OUZPJfpRqSQnOTCvr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101738555398870704584&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output on stack overflow in copiable format so others can benefit from any solution.

Comment: @David  it is on the link already

Answer (score 2):

Merge the value columns into a single column before the pivot, eg

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\david\Downloads\Test1.xlsx"), null, false),
    Sheet1_sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    FilterNullAndWhitespace = each List.Select(_, each _ <> null and (not (_ is text) or Text.Trim(_) <> "")),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Sheet1_sheet, "IsEmptyRow", each try List.IsEmpty(FilterNullAndWhitespace(Record.FieldValues(_))) otherwise false),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", -1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Section", each if [IsEmptyRow] then -1 else if try #"Added Index"[IsEmptyRow]{[Index]} otherwise true then [Index] else null),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each not [IsEmptyRow]),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Blank Rows", {"Section"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Section"}, {{"Rows", each _}}, GroupKind.Local),
    #"Selected Group" = #"Grouped Rows"[Rows]{1},
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Selected Group", {"IsEmptyRow", "Index", "Section"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ObjectID", Int64.Type}, {"Feld", type text}, {"Datentyp", type text}, {"boolValue", type text}, {"dateValue", type date}, {"intValue", Int64.Type}, {"stringValue", type text}, {"longStringValue", type text}, {"referencedObjectId", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[boolValue], Text.From([dateValue], "en-US"), Text.From([intValue], "en-US"), [stringValue], [longStringValue], Text.From([referencedObjectId], "en-US")}, ""), type text),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Datentyp", "boolValue", "dateValue", "intValue", "stringValue", "longStringValue", "referencedObjectId"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Feld]), "Feld", "Merged")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: That was great code...but one thing I left in my desription, I dont want the "output" table within query....that should be on different page anyways.... or it is expenditure for you to tweak it..? thx anyways

Comment: It already does that; it's the "Selected Group" step that eliminates the Output table.

Comment: Hmm yeah right, but what if I am transforming my data from Excel current book? I tried it and seems the coding isnt right in that case...
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content]